# Excel service on sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, excel-services

Trying to start excel services application web service application. The status just seems to be stuck on stopped. 
Timer service is running and so is excel calculation service. Any ideas?

Comment: I cant even seem to delete the service application. Just stays on processing.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably **delete** all excel services applications and follow the instructions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server-2010/hh223277(v=office.14)) to rebuild them.  But before doing so, take note of the account that it is running under.

If Excel Services was running using a service account, disregard the first section titled:  To create an account for the application pool

If, after associating the new Excel applications to the sharepoint web application you continue to have an issue, this may be a permissions issue.

To verify if this is the case, look for this error:
*“Event Viewer: Event 5239, Excel Services Application. There was an error in communicating with Excel Calculation Service (server address on port 32843, standard port for web services address ending with /ExcelService*.asmx)  exception: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."*

Try these steps:

1. Launch IIS Manager (Start Administrative Tools -> Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager)
2. Expand Servers and Expand Sites
3. Select SharePoint Web Services from list of available of sites.
4. Select Authentication from right panel and available authentications are displayed.
5. Disable ASP.NET Impersonation if enabled.

**`Please Mark This As Answer If It Solved Your Problem`**

Comment: Thank you but I had already tried disabling the authentication. I'm probabably being a idiot here but I cant even find whete to start the service. It just states it is stopped. I tried a powershell cmd to start it but it just reloaded the services web page. Probabaly using the wrong command.

Comment: Can i not just use the farm account to run the application service?

Comment: I can tell you that I have not even touched SharePoint 2010 in at least 6 years.  Now that I have moved my org to SP online, I cannot even give you a page reference to do the things in Central Admin that you need to do.  What you need to do is familiarize yourself with the cmdlets for SP 2010 here:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee534955(v%3Doffice.14)   and perform a sequence of commands that 1) get the web application 2) passes the web application to the remove sp services application, and then recreates the service application.

Comment: Using the Farm Account is a Major security risk.